# Block SMS Push Notification of a particular number in Android

Tags: android, push-notification, sms

I am developing an Android App which receives SMS from a particular number constantly. I want my App to parse the SMS and display to the user accordingly. I wrote a broadcast receiver which intercepts sms and I can read the message sent from a particular number. However I do not want the user to get a push notification when the mobile receives an SMS from the number. Is there any way I can go about it?

From the android developer website, it seems from Android 4.4+ we cannot use abortBroadcast function to avoid broadcasting to the other applications.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is no way you can block the SMS going to other applications. But We have achieved this by customising the android framework which is proprietary implementation.

Comment: Could you suggest a way to block atleast the push notifications for specific numbers and a clue on how I can approach this problem

Comment: I think it is not possible to do that.